# Get a comprehensive list of virulence factors for certain or all pathogens?

Tags: public-databases, microbial-genomics, pathogenicity

Is there a database with all known proteins/genes of specific pathogens such as Staph aureus and annotated whether it is a known virulence or resistance factor that idealy can be downloaded in table format?

Comment: Please consider accepting MP's answer. For my own stuff I found it really useful, its a good a question and really good answer.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you are looking for a resource like [VFDB](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjfw6vom4z9AhV0IX0KHZFaAa4QFnoECAkQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mgc.ac.cn%2FVFs%2F&usg=AOvVaw1AmmhEo5WZmOQGcDHHJ4gY) (virulence factor database). That table does annotate by bacterial species, so you can filter as you like.

You can download a description table or FASTA sequences from their [downloads page](http://www.mgc.ac.cn/VFs/download.htm) (see screenshot). Last update was 4 days ago, so they should be quite current.

[image]

For resistance genes, you could use something like [CARD](https://card.mcmaster.ca/) (Comprehensive Antibiotic Resistance Database), which also has a [downloads page](https://card.mcmaster.ca/download) where you can download a similar TSV table or FASTA sequences.

Both resources include web tools for predicting the presence of the elements of interest in sequences.

If you are looking for a state of the art prediction tool for such elements in genomes, you might look into [seqscreen](https://gitlab.com/treangenlab/seqscreen) from Todd Treangen's lab.

For a general purpose microbiological annotation and analysis resource, you might also look into [BV-BRG](https://www.bv-brc.org/), which succeeds PATRIC. I have only used PATRIC but BV-BRG seems very thorough.

I think that you are unlikely to find a resource that has *non-virulent/non-resistance* genes annotated.

Comment: Wow what a cool answer. Got to be the accepted answer, but lets wait. There are a number of microbiological bioinformaticians here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I saw the VFDB database, but I had concers how up to date it is. I am going to check out the other resources you mentioned.

Comment: @Soren added a note- VFDB was last updated 4 days ago. See screenshot.